# Pass MutableMap from one fragment to another, Android, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to send a MutableMap from one fragment to another.

But cannot find a way to do it.

I tried

```
R.id.fragment_skills -> {
            val fragment = SkillsFragment()
            val oldFrag = HomeFragment()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.javaClass.getSimpleName())
                .commit()
            doneButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.check)
            doneButton.alpha = 1.0f
            page = "skills"
           fragment.artData = oldFrag.artData
```

I see there is ways with put extra but cannot find one for a Mutable map.

The mutable map looks like this on both fragments.

```
var artData = mutableMapOf<String,Any>()
```

I get the info and popular the map in the first fragment but want to use that dats in the second fragment without downloading it all again. plus I want to make changes to the Map so I can re upload the changes later.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `mutableMapOf<String, Any>()` to `HashMap<String, Any>()` and then pass that as `Bundle` argument using `putSerializable(yourMap)` in your fragment transaction, and retrieve as an argument in the next fragment and deserialize it.

A bundle argument needs to implement `Serializable`, `mutableMapOf` does not, but `HashMap` does.